# Define dimensions of colorbar in matlab

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I create the following figure:

```
Naming = {'Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6'};

for i = 1:length(Naming);
    dat = 1+(30-1).*rand(365,5);
    time = datenum('2009-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'):datenum('2009-12-31',...
        'yyyy-mm-dd');
    dept = 1:5;

    figure(1);
    ax = subplot(3,2,i);
    contourf(time,dept,dat',1:5:30);
    shading flat;
    title(Naming{i});
    datetick('x','mmm','keepticks');
    AX{i} = get(ax,'position'); 
end
h = axes('Position',[0 0 1 1],'Visible','off');
c = colorbar;
x = get(c,'Position');
x(1) = AX{end}(1)+AX{end}(3)+0.02;
x(2) = AX{end}(2);
x(3) = 0.02;
x(4) = AX{1}(2)+AX{1}(4);
set(c,'Position',x);
```

Is there a better method for defining the width and height of the colorbar? At the moment the colorbar is positioned in the right location but the height is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to subtract the y-position of the bottom axes:

```
x(4) = AX{1}(2)+AX{1}(4)-AX{6}(2);
```

as for a better method: You're doing it pretty OK in my view...what do you think would be "better"?

Answer (score 1):

MathWorks provides a [solution](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-1DQ8BG/index.html?product=ML) for specifying the colorbar's width, that worked well for me.

Here is the example from the linked website, where the width of the colorbar is set to **0.03**:

```
pcolor(peaks);
c=colorbar;
x1=get(gca,'position');
x=get(c,'Position');
x(3)=0.03;
set(c,'Position',x)
set(gca,'position',x1)
```

Comment: At least in my case, this makes the plot shrink if you render it a few times.

Comment: I also tried this solution, and the associated plot window expands automatically to its original dimension and overlaps with the colorbar in my case.